# how to read and load a file with these characters in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, filereader

I have for example a file and within empleados.txt has this information
" x002 ; Peter ; Tor ; 1200.0 ; 1992/4/4 "
without quotes

Only I get to read the file when the file is inside " ; " if I have "/" I get no reading

thx

```
 public void ReadFile(String nameFile)  {
    FileReader file;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line;

    try {
        fichero = new FileReader(nombreFichero);
        lector = new BufferedReader(fichero);



        while ((linea = lector.readLine()) != null  ) {
           Employee temporalEmployee = new    Employee();
            GregorianCalendar calTemporal = new GregorianCalendar();




            String[]   temp = linea.split(";");


            ns.setDni(temp[0]);
            ns.setName(temp[1]);
            ns.setlastName(temp[2]);
            ns.setsalary((Float.parseFloat(temp[3])));

            calTemporal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(temp[4]));
            calTemporal.add(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(temp[5]));
            calTemporal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Integer.parseInt(temp[6]));

            ns.setDateOfHire(calTemporal);


       System.out.println(linea);

            ArraylistOfEmployee.add(ns);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (lector != null) {
                    lector.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
calTemporal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(temp[4]));
calTemporal.add(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(temp[5]));
calTemporal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Integer.parseInt(temp[6]));
```

--- to this ---

```
String[] temp2 = temp[4].split("/");
calTemporal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(temp2[0]));
calTemporal.add(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(temp2[1]));
calTemporal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Integer.parseInt(temp2[2]));
```

Comment: thanks for replying , now for example , if I had 2 GregorianCalendar , one for hiring date , and one for the end date of the contract , should create another String [ ] temp ?
thx

Comment: it depend of format of your data, if it will "x002 ; Peter ; Tor ; 1200.0 ; 1992/4/4 ; 1992/4/20" then you should use temp3

Comment: hank you very much for the reply, it has served me a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for the date bit instead of breaking it out. Your current split will leave all of the Date as a single field.

Something like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
 Date dateResult = format.parse(temp[4]));
```